# If condition to get userid from different fields from JSON

Tags: if-statement, splunk, splunk-query

I am working on a splunk query , where I need to get userid from two different places. This is the sample splunk event I have.

```
{
  "name": "HIVE-5336eac7-7974-43cb",
  "applicationId": "application_16831546",
  "mr2AppInformation": {},
  "runningContainers": -1,
  "endTime": "2023-05-15T13:30:08.110Z",
  "applicationTags": [
    "hive_20230515120843_b1778593-0dab",
    "userid=xxx"
  ],
  "allocatedMemorySeconds": 251266964,
  "state": "FINISHED",
  "allocatedMB": -1,
  "attributes": {
    "diagnostics": "Session timed out, lastDAGCompletionTime=1684157098509 ms, sessionTimeoutInterval=300000 ms\nSession stats:submittedDAGs=1, successfulDAGs=1, failedDAGs=0, killedDAGs=0\n"
  },
  "pool": "root.grp",
  "user": "hive",
  "allocatedVcoreSeconds": 43970,
  "progress": 100.0,
  "allocatedVCores": -1,
  "startTime": "2023-05-15T13:20:56.078Z"
}
```

In this if "user" field is hive then I would like to get the user id from ApplicationTags( userid=xxx).

I am extracting "user" field like below.
spath output=userid path=user

So I have this regex I want to use to get userid.

rex field=_raw "userid=(?.*)"]"

Now my question is I would like to write an if condition, when "user" is hive I would like to get the userid from user in application tag.

Please help.

I would like to write an if condition, when "user" is hive I would like to get the userid from user in application tag.

Answer (score 0):

An if condition to extract the user id from the application tags when the "user" field is "hive":

```
eval 'raw=_raw' | if(user=="hive", rex field=raw "userid=(?<userid>.*)\"", spath output=userid path=user)
```

An alternative approach:

```
index=<your_index_here> user=hive
| spath output=userid path=applicationTags{}
| search userid="*"
| rex field=userid "userid=(?<userid>.+)"
| table userid
```

This uses a search to filter events where the "user" field is equal to "hive" and then uses the spath to extract the "userid" value from the "applicationTags" field.

Comment: Hi Paul 
Thank you, one more question.
what should be the eval statement before if condition.

Comment: I edited the answer above (`eval 'raw=_raw'`)

Comment: Thank you , can we run if without an eval statement in splunk ?

| if(user=="hive", rex field=raw "userid=(?<userid>.*)\"", spath output=userid path=user)

this seems invalid without eval
Error : Unknown search command 'if'.


| eval user_dum= if(user=="hive", rex field=raw "userid=(?<userid>.*)\"", spath output=userid path=user)

this is also giving error " Error in 'EvalCommand': The expression is malformed."

Comment: did you not refresh the page and read my reply to your first comment?